# Tab completion in console for rake commands

Tags: shell, rake

I'm very happy to get tab completion with the following chunk of code in my .bashrc:

```
cd () {
    command cd "$@";
    if [ -f ./Rakefile ]; then
        complete -W "$(rake -T | awk 'NR != 1 {print $2}')" rake
    else
        complete -r rake
    fi
}
```

This command will be loaded when I enter a directory with cd. If a directory don't contain a rakefile a message 'bash: complete: rake: no completion specification' shows up. Is there a possibility to omit this message?

Thanks for your help
Matthias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do this:

```
complete -r rake 2>/dev/null
```

It's outputting the error when it tries to remove the completion spec when it's not present (already been removed). Just redirect stderr to dump the error message.